# Why does Blade waste his explosive?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-ii

Near the end of Blade II, Blade is captured by evil, genetically manipulating vampires. Though his weapons have all been confiscated, he still has the remote control for a bomb he embedded in the base of the skull of Reinhart, one of his chief enemies. He presses the button on the remote to reveal -- surprise! -- that it does not work because his own (human) weapons master, Scud, had been working for the evil vampires all along.

Reinhart pulls the bomb from his skull and hands it to Scud, at which point Blade reveals that he had known of Scud's treachery and secretly fixed the remote. Boom! He blows up Scud, leaving the vastly more powerful and better-armed Reinhart to be defeated in hand-to-hand combat.

If Blade could make the bomb work, why not detonate it while it was still in Reinhart's head? Scud is human and could have been dispatched in about a second without any weapons at all, yet Blade wastes the bomb on him and has to fight Reinhart unarmed.

In-universe explanation please.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason when Reinhart tell the "security" to waste him they approach Blade and use electric tonfas instead of just shooting him having already guns pointed at him.

It looks good and build tension. 
After that Blade have to escape with Whistler and then make a cool baptised in blood scene.